# Ionic APP and iOS 11 stuck in splash screen with infinite loading

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, loading, freeze, splash-screen

I developed an App in Ionic, all worked very well. Also I sent my app to the AppStore and passed the review stage.

After the app where approved, I downloaded the version from the AppStore and I realized the *production* App got stuck in the splash screen, with the spinner loading in the middle of the screen for infinite time.

I tried to debug the App that I sent with Xcode but now also my app (that previously worked well) and is stuck in the same part too!! weird

My endpoints are live in a server that are worked well (also I find very weird that the App passed the review..)

The log in xcode is the following:

```
2017-10-30 19:23:32.237209-0300 Club PO[10332:4430711] FATAL: OneSignal AppId format is invalid.
Example: 'b2f7f966-d8cc-11e4-bed1-df8f05be55ba'
2017-10-30 19:23:32.243192-0300 Club PO[10332:4430711] Apache Cordova native platform version 4.3.1 is starting.
2017-10-30 19:23:32.243305-0300 Club PO[10332:4430711] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2017-10-30 19:23:32.373394-0300 Club PO[10332:4430711] [MC] Lazy loading NSBundle MobileCoreServices.framework
2017-10-30 19:23:32.374762-0300 Club PO[10332:4430711] [MC] Loaded MobileCoreServices.framework
2017-10-30 19:23:32.380800-0300 Club PO[10332:4430711] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2017-10-30 19:23:32.389913-0300 Club PO[10332:4430711] Using UIWebView
2017-10-30 19:23:32.392638-0300 Club PO[10332:4430711] [CDVTimer][handleopenurl] 0.105977ms
2017-10-30 19:23:32.395315-0300 Club PO[10332:4430711] [CDVTimer][intentandnavigationfilter] 2.561986ms
2017-10-30 19:23:32.395519-0300 Club PO[10332:4430711] [CDVTimer][gesturehandler] 0.064969ms
2017-10-30 19:23:32.508949-0300 Club PO[10332:4430711] [CDVTimer][splashscreen] 113.343000ms
2017-10-30 19:23:32.523217-0300 Club PO[10332:4430711] [CDVTimer][statusbar] 14.133990ms
2017-10-30 19:23:32.526091-0300 Club PO[10332:4430711] [CDVTimer][keyboard] 2.716005ms
2017-10-30 19:23:32.526343-0300 Club PO[10332:4430711] Starting Facebook Connect plugin
2017-10-30 19:23:32.526430-0300 Club PO[10332:4430711] [CDVTimer][facebookconnectplugin] 0.211000ms
2017-10-30 19:23:32.526570-0300 Club PO[10332:4430711] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 134.099007ms
2017-10-30 19:23:32.667525-0300 Club PO[10332:4430711] refreshPreferences: HangTracerEnabled: 0
2017-10-30 19:23:32.667577-0300 Club PO[10332:4430711] refreshPreferences: HangTracerDuration: 500
2017-10-30 19:23:32.667602-0300 Club PO[10332:4430711] refreshPreferences: ActivationLoggingEnabled: 0 ActivationLoggingTaskedOffByDA:0
2017-10-30 19:23:33.065090-0300 Club PO[10332:4430711] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.
2017-10-30 19:23:33.113662-0300 Club PO[10332:4430711] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2017-10-30 19:23:33.689447-0300 Club PO[10332:4430787] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
2017-10-30 19:23:33.690025-0300 Club PO[10332:4430787] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
2017-10-30 19:23:53.167722-0300 Club PO[10332:4430786] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1001
2017-10-30 19:23:53.186367-0300 Club PO[10332:4430711] Failed to load webpage with error: The request timed out.
2017-10-30 19:23:53.191988-0300 Club PO[10332:4430787] Task <8DE2F0BC-14FC-47A8-9049-99895860ED86>.<0> HTTP load failed (error code: -999 [1:89])
```

My plugin list is:

```
cordova-plugin-compat 1.0.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-facebook4 1.9.1 "Facebook Connect"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.4.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-nativestorage 2.2.2 "NativeStorage"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 3.2.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.1.3 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.2 "Whitelist"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
onesignal-cordova-plugin 2.2.2 "OneSignal Push Notifications"
phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner 6.0.1 "BarcodeScanner"
phonegap-plugin-push 2.1.0 "PushPlugin"
```

ionic --version: 2.2.3
cordova --version: 6.5.0

Comment: Well, the logs are quite explicit about a connection timing out, though it doesn’t give details about which request. While running the dev version of your app, debug it with the web inspector in Safari and check network requests and the console for details.

Comment: There should not be infinite loading, the app *should* normally crash after some time with a watchdog timeout failure.

Comment: check whether your web service is running properly.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing, but it's random. I debugged with Safari and there's not much to go on there as it's sitting on the about:blank page. I was hoping it had something to do with using WKWebView, but I see you're using UIWebView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally solved uploading the .IPA app to the appstore again, thanks anyway!

Comment: You really should provide your solution here and mark it as the accepted answer.  It helps the community and improves your user stats too!

Comment: So what was the solution?

Comment: @Chris clean and build a new archive (with new version) and upload again